# Attempting to do a trasversal of a custom data type (directory tree)

Tags: haskell

I have created a custom data type which consists of the following:

```
data DirTree = Root Node
-- a Root Node, which ideally should be a Directory
data Node = Dir [Node] String | File String Integer
-- a directory with an arbitrary number of Nodes and a name, or a File with a name and size
```

Now, I have been attempting to recreate unix-y functions on said DirTree, such as stat (which takes up 5 functions but that's another problem), and listing functions.

One of the listing functions I wanted to do was to give a  `[[String ]]` containing all possible paths from the root any other Node, for example, said function for:

```
root
    ---> folder1 
           ---> file1

    ---> folder2
           --->file2
           --->file3
```

would give something like:

`[["/"],["/","folder1"],["/","folder1","file1"],["/","folder2"],["/","folder2","file2"],["/","folder2","file3"]]`

It sounds to me like I should do maps recursively concatenating the previous path with all other paths resulting from the nodes, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Below is a crappy attempt:

```
find :: Node -> [[String]]
find (File name _) = [[name]] -- maybe?
find (Dir as name) = map (name:) (getNames as) ++ find as
-- getNames simply returns a list of the names of each node in the directory
-- how would the right side get the previous list of names?
```

UPDATE: second attempt:

```
find :: DirTree -> [[String]]
find (Root (File name _)) = [[[]]]
find (Root (Dir as name)) = [[name]] ++ find' (Dir as name)

find' :: Node -> [[String]]
find' (File name _) = [[name]]
find' (Dir [] name) = [[name]]
find' (Dir as name) = map (name:) (concatMap (find') as) -- name concatenated to each result of find' over all nodes on the directory

-- find (Root (Dir [(File "file1" 4), (File "file2" 5),(Dir [(File "file3" 5)] "dir2")] "dir"))
-- [["dir"],["dir","file1"],["dir","file2"],["dir","dir2","file3"]]
```

Comment: Hint: What result would you expect for `find folder1` and `find folder2`? Try and see how you can get to `find root` from these two.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Did you refer to my (now posted) second attempt? I think I got how to do it, although I don't get very much the concatMap I did there...